# UV Unwrapping Shading Artifacts

Tags: texturing, uv, faces

I'm wondering why when I unwrap my mesh it creates weird shading artifacts on some places but not on others. I've tried using different unwrap methods such as cube projection, cylinder projection, sphere projection etc. I've even marked the necessary seams and tried smart uv project, but I still end up with some kind of artifacting.

*FYI, there's no z-fighting going on, no overlapping of faces.

Example:
[image: Unwrap artifacts]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe pack your image and share your file (share the link): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here you go https://pasteall.org/blend/b305643e1c154e63a3a56b8244682826

Answer (score 2):

Switch your normal *Image Texture* node from *sRGB* to *Non-Color*:

[image]